# Почему printf("%d", UINT_MAX) выводит -1?

Tags: c

Язык Си. Я хотел узнать верхний предел переменной unsigned int. Я написал вот такой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d", UINT_MAX);


    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Мне выводит значение -1. Почему? В книге Язык программирования Си, значение равно 65535. И как узнать какое значение у меня на компьютере?

У меня Windows 10 64bit, среда Dev C++ 5.11, Компилятор TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64bit.

Answer (score 4):

Потому что  `%d` выводит signed. И 65535 (0xFFFF) как раз и есть -1. Используйте `%u` для unsigned.

Comment: Вот авторы книги интересные такие. До этой темы они об этом не написали(про формат вывода) и как я сам догадался бы?

Comment: и в самой теме про signed и unsigned они про формат не написали и дали задание определить пределы переменных. Такое ощущение, что они книгу делали тяп-ляп

Comment: Авторы Брайан Керниган и Денис Ритчи

Comment: @Rikimaru [как я сам догадался бы] Если Вы написали спецификатор вывода %d, значит Вы уже прочли про спецификаторы вывода. Просто не обратили внимание, что unsigned требует спецификатора %u.

Comment: @pepsicola1 я понял, надо читать предметный указатель) А я ожидал от авторов, что они сами последовательно напишут об этом

Answer (score 2):

Спецификатор формата `%d` требует аргумента типа `int`, а вы указали аргумент типа `unsigned int`. Указывать аргументы типа `unsigned int` для `%d` *разрешается*, но только в том случае, когда фактическое значение `unsigned int` попадает в диапазон типа `int`. В вашем случае это требование не соблюдено. Поэтому поведение не определено. Никакого смысла в наблюдаемом вами выводе нет.

Почему вы вдруг взялись использовать формат `%d` для `unsigned int`? Для вывода значений типа `unsigned int` предназначен формат `%u`. Им и пользуйтесь.

Comment: Дело в том, что я изучаю Си по книге Брайна Кернигана и Дениса Ритчи и они, до этой темы, так и в самой теме про signed и unsigned про формат вывода %u не писали. И как бы я сам догадался?

Comment: @Rikimaru, потому что эта книга (и другие подобные) всего лишь введение в язык, а не подробное описание. Всегда надо справляться в документации. В вашем случае - как только вы обнаружили что `printf` выводит что-то не то, идете [сюда, например](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) и смотрите что вы сделали не так.